# jQuery add/remove class to elements with in various similar lists without conflicting with other list

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to add and remove a class to input type radio button list using jQuery.

I have following list:

```
<div>
    <dd>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" value="75" class="validate-custom-configurable  radiobutton_select">
        5
    </label>
</dd>
<dd>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" value="76" class="validate-custom-configurable">
        4
    </label>
</dd>
<dd>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" value="77" class="validate-custom-configurable">
        9
    </label>
</dd>
</div>
<div>
<dd>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" value="545" class="validate-custom-configurable  radiobutton_select">
        small
    </label>
</dd>
<dd>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" value="555" class="validate-custom-configurable">
        large
    </label>
</dd>
</div>
```

jQuery code:

```
jQuery('dd label .validate-custom-configurable').click(function(){
        var parent = jQuery(this).parents('dd');
        jQuery(parent).each(function(i, el){
            el = jQuery(el);
            el.find("input").removeClass('radiobutton_select');
        })
        jQuery(this).addClass('radiobutton_select');
    });
```

I have to add a class "radiobutton_select" to selected radio button and remove this from others.

Please help.

Cheers!!

Comment: Show us your javascript code.

Comment: @user2019037 I've updated javascript code in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see output below ,use this code

- First register an change handler
- remove class from all radio buttons excepts this one
- Add Class to this one

```js
  $('div>dd label input[type="radio"]').change(function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
         $(this).addClass('radiobutton_select');
        $(this).closest('div').find('input[type="radio"]').not($(this)).removeClass('radiobutton_select');}
         else
        $(this).removeClass('radiobutton_select');
        })
```

```css
.radiobutton_select{
margin-left:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <dd>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" value="75"  name="myradio" class="validate-custom-configurable  radiobutton_select">
        5
    </label>
</dd>
<dd>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" value="76" name="myradio" class="validate-custom-configurable">
        4
    </label>
</dd>
<dd>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" value="77" name="myradio" class="validate-custom-configurable">
        9
    </label>
</dd>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually I'm trying to make it work through parents of input[type="radio"]. because I have other lists on the page with same structure. This way it will also take them into account. It'd be better if you suggest something using parents as well.

Comment: "validate-custom-configurable" class is only on thse radio buttonss?

Comment: No, it's also used for others

Comment: No, It's used for others as well. I've updated my question with jquery code I'm trying to use. Please check that.

Comment: check my edited code now is it different than others?

Comment: No, It is messing with other lists, which are using same format. Please check I've updated my question with complete html code.

Comment: @AnuragSharma edited the answer check if it differentiates now? or else you will cave to giv an id to holding div

Comment: No, it is still same. Can you please try with two different div as I mentioned in my question. And see if class is applied to two different radio buttons in different lists. As per code this class is applied to only one radio button through out the HTML.

Comment: @AnuragSharma edited see, it should work now

Comment: Awesome!!! Great work friend. Many thanks.

Comment: No problem glad to see that it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

Use This

```
    $('input[type="radio"]').change(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
     $(this).addClass('radiobutton_abc');
    $('input[type="radio"]').not($(this)).removeClass('radiobutton_select');}
     else
    $(this).removeClass('radiobutton_xyz');
    });
```